# Java Swing GUI in a Centos 7 Docker container on a Windows Host

Tags: java, docker, swing

I am building a Docker image FROM centos:7 (I am flexible on the base Linux image) which will run a Java Swing application on a Windows 10 host. When attempting to run the Docker image, I get the following exception:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1763) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1838) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
        at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:272) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
        at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
```

Am I using the wrong Linux flavor or have I not configured it correctly? I would like the resulting image to be standalone and not require any additional software to be installed on the host machine. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to run a Java Swing application on Windows, you need to run it directly on Windows, not from a Docker container. In Linux it is - as far as I know - already pretty tricky to use GUI applications from Docker, but doing it from Windows is probably either not possible or extremely hard to do, and will likely result in poor usability if it is possible.

Comment: If you want to link into a self-contained unit to run on Windows, it is probably better to look at jlink and/or jpackage in recent Java version (e.g. Java 17).

Comment: You will be better off installing a JVM on the host and running the Java application directly, than installing an X server on the host and trying to convince Docker to talk to it.  There is not a portable way for a container to access the host's display.

Comment: There is a very portable way for Java to connect to the host's display. It goes via X and the network. If configured correctly, the container can run on any machine on the network and create a display on the same X server. But yes, it has to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want your docker container to open a window on the windows machine, configure an X server (https://teamdynamix.umich.edu/TDClient/47/LSAPortal/KB/ArticleDet?ID=1797) so it accepts connections, then tell the container by setting the environment variable `DISPLAY` how to connect to that X server.

Upon next start of the container the error should be gone or different.